# Working with AJAX and JSP

Tags: ajax, web-services, jsp

Basically I just learnt AJAX yesterday and still learning. I have a project right now which requires me to write a Web Service method to search for shops. Everything is find but then again, I'm calling the web service using JSP, I would like to display the result using AJAX.

When I test my AJAX, it works when I integrate it with PHP file but may I know if it works for JSP kind of file? If so, is there any tutorial that show steps for me to learn?

If another case, if AJAX couldn't be perform using JSP, is there any other way for me to use AJAX with my Web Service?

Comment: Ajax works with both PHP and JSP

Comment: Hey, thanks for the heads up, I've found a tutorial to guide me. Thank you very much for your time and knowledge.